# I am large and I am small, What word am I?

Tags: riddle, word

> I come before 1, after 2 and before 3

I am large and small

What word am I talking about?

> I don't come after 0 but do come before 10

Comment: I think there can be multiple plausible answers to this at the moment. Adding a couple of lines more might prevent it from becoming too broad.

Comment: It was hard to add another line without giving the answer away. But I tried

Answer (score 2):

> Big  which is a small 3 letter word. Big one, Too big and Big Three also Big Ten

Answer (score -2):

I would say the word

> **Dictionary**

Clue 1:

> "I" come before the word "One", after that comes the word "Two" and before "Two" there is "Three" (alphabetical order).

Clue 2:

> "I" don't come after "Zero" but "Do" come before "Ten"

Comment: That is not the order given in the question.

Comment: You don't explain why "I am large and small"...